# rdiff-backup script not working on this server, but does work on an other server

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, rdiff-backup

I have a rdiff-backup script that isn't really working on a specific server. The script I'm using, is for allmost all the servers the same and they all work fine, except for one server. The first time I ran the script with `bash` it went fine, it showed no errors and backed up everything.

But if I run the script now with crontab or bash, is refuses to work.It starts with:
`Warning: Access Control List file not found`. Currently i'm running the script to check which errors it produces, so I got some more information for you guys to help me out.

But do you have some tips for me to start searching for the problem?

Edit:
Some of the errors im getting, list is too long to post.

`UpdateError srv/chroot/web/proc/1/attr/exec [Errno 22] Invalid argument`
`UpdateError srv/chroot/web/proc/1/attr/fscreate [Errno 22] Invalid argument`
`UpdateError srv/chroot/web/proc/1/attr/keycreate [Errno 22] Invalid argument`
`UpdateError srv/chroot/web/proc/1/attr/prev [Errno 22] Invalid argument`
`UpdateError srv/chroot/web/proc/1/attr/sockcreate [Errno 22] Invalid argument`
`UpdateError srv/chroot/web/proc/1/autogroup Updated mirror temp file /var/bacula/storage/rdiff-backup/averroes2/srv/chroot/web/proc/1/rdiff-backup.tmp.68132 does not match source`

Comment: Try add `--no-acls` in your rdiff-backup script

Comment: Why should I add --no-acls, when it ran normally the first time? That doesn't make any sense

Comment: maybe there are differences in the versions of installed packages between their systems that may be causing this problem.

Comment: @FedericoSierra The versions of the installed packages are on both systems the same.

Comment: is shared the file system? mount options are the same?

Comment: @FedericoSierra Can you explain this a bit more? I don't really get what you are trying to say.

Comment: I believe that if you are trying to write in a mounted filesystem differently from other systems may be causing this error.

Comment: The warning "Access Control List file not found" occurred only once on each of the two external HDs I back up to from one laptop, presumably after some upgrade.  At the next backup, the warning was gone.  Hence, I'm not sure it's related to your other problems.